# Codeigniter- get query results

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to get all query results where I get the id's from another query. I get all relevant id's from both table but i can show only one result in my view. Where is my folt, and how can I fix this?
my Controller:

```
$results = $this->my_model->hd($query_array ,$limit, $offset);
$data['r']= $results ['rows'];
$data['num_results']= $results ['num_rows'];
$id_str = '';

foreach($results['rows'] as $row){
  $id_str .= $row->id . ',';
}

$id_str = rtrim($id_str, '');
$doff = $this->my_model->off($id_str);
$data['o']= $doff ['rows'];
```

My Model:

```
function hd($query_array,$limit, $offset){

  //result query
  $q = $this->db->select('*')
                  ->from('a')
                  ->limit($limit, $offset);

  if (strlen($query_array['cy'])){
    $q->like('cy', $query_array['cy']);
  }
   if (strlen($query_array['cat'])){
    $q->where('cat', $query_array['cat']);
  }
   if (strlen($query_array['rat'])){
    $q->where('rat', $query_array['rat']);
  }

  $ret['rows'] = $q->get()->result();    
  $q = $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count', FALSE)
                  ->from('r');

  if (strlen($query_array['cy'])){
    $q->like('cy', $query_array['cy']);
  }
   if (strlen($query_array['cat'])){
    $q->where('cat', $query_array['cat']);
  }
   if (strlen($query_array['rat'])){
    $q->where('rat', $query_array['rat']);
  }

  $tmp = $q->get()->result();
  $ret['num_rows'] = $tmp[0]->count;
  return $ret;        
}              
function off($id_str){
  $off_a = $this->db->select('*')
                    ->from('off')
                    ->where('r_id', $id_str);
  $ret['rows'] = $off_a->get()->result();
  return $ret;
}
```

I show in my view the result in a foreach loop. I tried to fix this problem since three days by my self and google, but no luck.

Comment: please show your output and the expected output

Comment: even if I show the array with print_r(id_str), it bring me all the id's but my $data['o'] is only the first one, I don't know how to bring all the data where i got the id's from.

Comment: You'll have to use ->where_in instead of ->where if you're passing multiple ids, I'd use group_concat or subQuery in mysql instead of having to do foreach & build the ids manually

Comment: @ahmad have I to change all my Model?